# Why does rejection of preceding promise prevent execution of following promise(s) and any code following it?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
let jj =  Promise.resolve('value')
let oo = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  let randNo = Math.floor(Math.random() * 87) 

  if(randNo < 4) {
    resolve('resolved')
  } else {
    reject('rej')
  }

})

async function kk () {
  console.log(await oo)
  console.log(await jj)
  console.log('async')
}
console.log('synchronous')
kk()
```

Hello everybody, I am learning promises and async execution in JS. I want to know why rejection of oo promise prevents execution of jj promise plus any code following it? Thank you

Comment: Basically you can think of rejecting a Promise like throwing an Exception. If it is not caught, subsequent code wont be executed.

Comment: ohhhh, that makes so much sense, thanks man

Answer (score 0):

For the same reason that throwing an error prevents executing any code following it:

```
function k () {
  throw 'rej'
  console.log('value');
}
k();
```

A rejected promise is similar to throwing an exception, except that it happens asynchronously. If you need to catch the rejection, you can do so:

```
async function kk () {
  try {
    console.log(await oo)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('caught an error', err);
  }
  console.log(await jj)
  console.log('async')
}
```